# How to get related object from JSON with Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

My client needs to send a POST request with `people` objects formatted as JSON:

```
{
   "name":"Smith",
   "adress": {
      "city":"LA",
      "state":"CA",
      "adressId":123123
   },
   "matricule":"123"
}
```

My server is a REST service and need to persist this object. My domain contains a people bean, and an adress one with a `many to one` relation.

My controller which is getting the request is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/people", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public void createPeople(@RequestBody People people) {
    ...
}
```

The problem is the server responds an error because it doesn't succeed in mapping the embedded `adress` entity into the `people` one. It works if I remove the `adress` object.

Is there any configuration to do to make embedded object working?

Edit :

```
@Table(name = "people")
public class People {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "peopleId")
    private Integer peopleId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "matricule")
    private String matricule;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="adressId")
    private Adress adress;

    // Getters and Setters

}
```

Error log:

```
DEBUG: [mars-28 11:25:47,049] mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - 
Resolving exception from handler [...createPeople()]: org.springframework.http.converter.
HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field 
"adressId" (Class Adress), not marked as ignorable
    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@456ce9; line: 1,
column: 106]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
Unrecognized field "adressId" (Class adress), not marked as ignorable
    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@456ce9; line: 1, 
column: 106]
```

My Adress class contains:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "adressId")
private Integer adressId;

@Column(name = "city")
private String city;
@Column(name = "state")
private String state;
```

Note that adress objects are already persist in DB

Comment: Please show your `People` class and post the detailed error message you are getting. Also make sure you have Jackson on your classpath. If you set the log level for spring mvc to `DEBUG`, you will get detailed information why the mapping failed.

Comment: @atamanroman I add my People entity, do you also need constructors?

Comment: Stack trace would help :) In the JSON provided, matricule is a number, instead of a String, which it is the case in the domain model class. You should show us Manager code as well.

Comment: @atamanroman thanks I forget the spring DEBUG mode. I add a part of the error on my post

Comment: City and state fields are missing in Manager class. In any case, the error shows that jackson expects the addressId field. You could try to use @JsonIgnore annotation in this field.

Comment: @Fractaliste already exists in the db before the request?

Comment: @Fractaliste one workaround that I can think of is to have 2 objects, createPeople(\@ModelAttribute('people') people, \@ModelAttribute('people.adress') manager), i would also put  \@JsonIgnore on adress like jaranda suggested